# Can I format a USB drive using a laptop as a technician PC and having my desktop as my destination PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, operating-systems

I was told that formatting a USB drive with a laptop would make the format not match the desktop and that it wouldn't work. The reason I'm doing this is because I just bought a new PC I have to build. All I have is a laptop to make the OS and I forgot to buy a disk drive for my build so I can't use a disk. I don't have another desktop to format the USB drive. I suppose I could use a library computer.

Comment: “I was told that formatting a USB drive with a laptop would make the format not match the desktop and that it wouldn't work.” Makes no sense. There is nothing about formatting with a laptop that would prevent the USB drive from being used with a desktop.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, might "used to make sense". Could he be talking about what used to be true when USB drives first came out?  If you formatted NTFS back in the day, then the ACL would be assigned to the creators SID and you would have to take ownership to get it back? .. I seem to remember something like this when USB was new.. which is NO LONGER TRUE.  Back in the day, I used only fat32 for this reason.

Comment: What you wrote would only make sense if laptop and desktop use different OS, linke Window,s Linux and MacOS. But even in this case it is not impossible, you just have to select the correct file-system when formatting the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You were told wrong. End of story.

Laptops and desktops are, from the POV of external USB drives identical and interoperable.

There are some gotchas with interoperability between Windows, Linux and Macs, because they can use different filesystem's which may not be read by other OS's, and there are some cases where these are beneficial - but a filesystem formatted to use the FAT filesystem will work between pretty much any computer without fiddling, although there are dome limits around file names and file permissions.